# Redux tookit access store values outside of component

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

How can I access `redux-toolkit store` variables outside of React component? In React components I could access it with

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';    
const isAuthenticated: boolean = useSelector(
        (state: RootState) => state.user.isAuthenticated,
      );
```

Since useSelector isn't allowed to access outside of React. Or should I pass variables when I dispatch in React Component? I need access variable in `createAsyncThunk` API call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) will pass in a `thunkApi` object as the second argument to the payload creator callback and on that object, you can call the `getState` method.

```js
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (someArg, thunkApi) => {
    const state = thunkApi.getState()

    // whatever logic you need.

    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(someArg)
    return response.data
  }
)
```

Comment: thank you, now it is right. But I am using typescript, and the `state` is `unknown.`

Comment: `const state: RootState = thunkApi.getState();`  I tried to use it, but cannot

Comment: "it cannot" could mean everything, including "you have no power in your apartment, so the PC is off", so please add more info. Are you getting an error message?

In general, for usage with TypeScript and thunkApi, see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk

Comment: sorry, thank you for your help, I used it incorrectly, I called `thunkApi.getStore();` instead of `thunkApi.getState();`